# Selecting Value of Sibling Node When Node = X

Tags: xpath

When looking at this XML tree:

```
<ids>
   <id>
      <id>1</id>
      <qty>0.0000</qty>
   </id>
   <id>
      <id>2</id>
      <qty>0.0000</qty>
   </id>
   <id>
      <id>3</id>
      <qty>0.0000</qty>
   </id>
   <id>
      <id>4</id>
      <qty>10.0000</qty>
   </id>
   <id>
      <id>5</id>
      <qty>0.0000</qty>
   </id>
</ids>
```

How would one go about choosing the qty with a sibling id of 4?

So far I've tried:

`<xsl:value-of select="ids/id[id = '4']/qty"/>`

`<xsl:value-of select="ids/id/qty[../id = '4']"/>`

However, the only result that is ever returned is `qty = 0.0000`.

Comment: Note that your XML is not _well-formed_. One `<id>` tag is missing.

Comment: My apologies, a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/ids/id[id='4']/qty
```